# Is OkHttp from squareup REST based library?

Tags: android

Couldn't find, whether it was answered earlier.

Is OkHttp library  from squareup ,REST based or not?
Kindly provide some webpage link that mention this.

Answer (score 5):

> Is OkHttp library from squareup ,REST based or not?

OkHttp is an HTTP client library. You can make REST-style requests with it, but you do not *have* to make REST-style requests with it. The same holds true for any general HTTP client API (`HttpURLConnection`, Volley, Apache HttpClient, Ion, etc.).

[Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) is Square's library that is more strongly tied to REST-style requests.

Comment: Does OkHttp library open Http connection for network requests?

Comment: @AnishMittal: Yes, that is what an HTTP client does.